# Android Monerujo - Node connection failed! Check Username / Password

Tags: monerujo

I've been trying a few 14.0.2 public nodes and even my own with a user/pass set. Every time I try to connect to my wallet using the Android monerujo app, it keeps giving me the error:

**Node Connection Failed - Check username/password**

What causes this error? What username/password is it even checking?

Comment: Can you check the version of Monerujo you are using? Go to the three vertical dots in the top-right corner and tap "About". Mine is `1.11.4 'Chernushka' (174)`

Comment: same. 1.11.4 version

Comment: Hmm. You shouldn't need a username/password for the node itself. You obviously need a password to unlock your wallet but check that you haven't set a node password. The screen to do this is on the advanced node selection screen (tap the little magnifying glass to get a list of nodes, then tap a node). I run a public node and I do not require the user to put a username and password in to use my node.

Comment: I did, still says same error. I tried it on multiple wallets already.

Comment: I have the same problem, iot only applies to one of my wallets, the other one i am able to access just fine. Can someone please help?

Comment: @Zeitgeist - Have you already tried restoring from the 25 word mnemonic seed?